# How does one prove that if function's partial derivative respect to every variable is zero, function is constant?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

How does one prove that if function's partial derivative respect to every variable that the function defines over is zero function is constant function? I just noticed it, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: I think you need to state hypotheses with respect to an open set and be a bit more accurate about what you are asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose the function $f(x,y)$ is non-constant and its partial derivatives exist everywhere. Then we have some $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ such that $f(x,y)\ne f(x',y')$. If $f(x,y)=f(x',y)=f(x,y')$ then these are distinct from $f(x',y')$, otherwise one of $f(x',y)$ or $f(x,y')$ is not $f(x,y)$. This means we only have to worry about one of the two variables! Lets say $f(x,y)\ne f(x',y)$ (the other cases are identical). By the Mean Value Theorem, we have some $c\in (x,x')$ such that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(c,y)=\frac{f(x',y)-f(x,y)}{x'-x}\ne 0$$
thus the partial derivatives are not everywhere $0$.

You should be able to extend this to arbitrarily many variables on your own.

Comment: Does this not assume continuity of the function?

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=f(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})$ and $f_{x_{1}}=f_{x_{2}}=...=f_{x_{n}}=0$.Because $f_{x_{1}}=0$, we can get $f=g(x_{2},...,x_{n})$ which is not depended on $x_{1}$. Then we have 
$y=g(x_{2},...,x_{n})$ and $g_{x_{2}}=...=g_{x_{n}}=0$. So from the recursion, we can say $f=c$ which is not depended on $x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}$.

Answer (score -3):

Let $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ be a function such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=0\,\forall i=1,2,\dots,n$.

Because $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}=0$, the function does not depend on $x_1$

Because $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}=0$, the function does not depend on $x_2$ either.

Continuing this, we come to conclusion that the function does not depend on any of the variables, and hence it is a constant.