# Do partial derivatives determine function uniquely?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

When we talk about functions of one variable, we have less complicated situations compared to the case in functions of several variables.

In the one variable case, for continuous functions satisfying the following property

If $f'(x) = g'(x)$ , then $f(x) = g(x) + C$  for a concstat $C$.

as  a corollary of the Mean Value Theorem.

By defining piecewise functions, we could produce more and more but I want to focus on continuous ones.

When we talk about functions of several variables, we do not have 'derivative'. Instead, we have a set of partial derivatives. Similar to the case in the one-variable functions, do we have this uniqueness property in that sense for continuous functions of multi-variable? In particular, are there continuous functions of two variables / three variables having the same set of partial derivatives at every point in a closed and bounded region in the plane / space which are not in the relation of uniqueness in the previous sense?

Comment: For the case of two variables, you have the result if the partial derivatives agree on an open connected set in the plane

Comment: Actually, I am looking for a proof or at least an idea, could you please explain how we get it?

Comment: See e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494128/how-does-one-prove-that-if-functions-partial-derivative-respect-to-every-variab